# Rails Routing, how to put username before posts url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have routes like this :

> http://localhost:3000/posts/post-title

i want to make my routes be like this :

> http://localhost:3000/username/posts/post-title

Is there anyone who can teach me How to do that?

Thank You

Comment: It is not problem, what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Do you want username dynamic of its just as static string.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routes.rb

1 =>

```
get '/:username/posts/:id', to: "controller#action", as: my_custom_route
```

Here by you need to pass 2 dynamic param value with this path 1 -> username, 2-> post_title

```
my_custom_route_path(username: username_value, id: post_title)
```

2 =>

If you want just username as static in every routes for this action then

```
get '/username/posts/:id', to: "controller#action", as: :my_custom_route
```

Here you need to pass only one dynamic param that is post_title

```
my_custom_route(id: post_title)
```

Comment: im using friendly_id gem on my post model. i got this error can't find record with friendly id: "My Third Post"

Comment: in my posts_controller      i have  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])

Comment: @dhaniel so far as I know friendly id creates unique I'd for your post with dash-  or underscore separated . Please check while passing I'd you should provide unique I'd which is generated by friendly -id gem which means that it should be like this `my_route_path(username : uername_val, id: @post.username)`.. so far as I know friendly _id creates a separate column username for the model. So while pass I'd use `@post.username` so that you can fetch `Post.friendly.fins(Params[:I'd])` . hopefully you understand . Let me know for further guidance. :)

Comment: if i change my url to http://localhost:3000/users/Dhaniel/posts/my-fourth-post its working

Comment: maybe you kwno how to change %20 into dash- using friendly_id gem ?

Comment: @dhaniel, how did u get %20 including routes. I think it's friendly _id version issue, did you use `@post.usernsme`? Or check stable version

Comment: i dont know why i got %20.. if i use id: @post.username i got undefined method `username'

Comment: my friendly gem is 5.2 version

Comment: @dhaniel I think it's slug the column which creates friemdly_id so let's try `id: @post.slug`

Comment: @dhaniel great to know that. Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you. :)